# Write into database in backgroundservice - Android Studio / Java

Tags: java, android

Im rather a beginner in programming an App for Android. And now I started programming one, which reads a Webpage and saves some data of it into a Database/Table.
I wanna add, that the app takes the website in a backgroundservice and compares it with the Database. Then it should popup a notification on your handy, if something has changed. The problem is, that im already creating the Database with the DatabaseHelper Class in the MainActivity, so when i wanna add someting in the Service Class to the Database, I need the MainActivity intent i think, but I dont know how.

relevant Code in MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
  Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Hintergrundservice.class);
  PendingIntent startServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, startServiceIntent, 0);
  c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()+1000*10);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,c.getTimeInMillis(),1000*10,startServicePendingIntent);
}
```

relevant DatabaseHelper class:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table Vertretungsplan (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,DATUM TEXT, TAG TEXT, KLASSE TEXT, STUNDE TEXT, LEHRER TEXT, FACH TEXT, RAUM TEXT, LEHRERVON TEXT, FACHALT TEXT)");
}
```

And thats currently the backgroundservice class:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hintergrundprozess wurde ausgeführt!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("MyActivity","Hintergrundprozess");
    //write into Database
    stopSelf();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need the MainActivity intent?

Comment: First of all, I think you need to change your create query to:
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...."

Comment: After that I can't find the place that you compare your current database to the new incoming data

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a second instance of `DatabaseHelper` in your service.